# How to fix 'SVG filter not working on IE but working on Chrome and Firefox'

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this SVG file and I need to use in my project but during testing I found out that it is not working on IE and Edge but working perfectly on Chrome and Firefox. When I debugging I found out that the  tag is not showing correctly. Below is my SVG code.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="326" height="471" viewBox="0 0 326 471">
  <defs>
    <style>.a{stroke:#fff;fill:url(#a);}.b{stroke:none;}.c{fill:none;stroke:none;}</style>
    <linearGradient id="a" x1="0.789" y1="0.864" x2="-0.232" y2="-0.463" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fcfcfc"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f3f3f3"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="myFilter" x="0" y="0" width="326" height="471" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset dy="1" input="SourceAlpha"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" result="c"/>
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.329"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="c"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g class="d" filter="url(#myFilter)" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)">
    <g class="a" transform="translate(323 467) rotate(180)">
      <rect class="b" width="320" height="465" rx="10"/>
      <rect class="c" width="320" height="465" rx="10"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Result on Chrome:
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLSA7.png)

Result on IE:
[IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaKD0.png)

The filter not showing on IE:
[Border missing on IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXbyE.png)

I tried method below:-
1. Set the filter via style tag in HTML.
2. Set the filter via style tag in head tag.

But none of them working.

Note: The filter is use to show a shadow border effect on the side of SVG.

Comment: One solution would be accepting that not everything is working in IE, and that a shadow is only for the looks. An other option would be using a plain HTML element with rounded corners and a `box-shadow`